# ArrayList Menu Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to make a menu that list the .txt files in a directory. For example, if i have jonsmith12.txt , lenovo123.txt , dell123.txt in the directory how would I make an arraylist menu of:

Please choose one of the following:

1. jonsmith12
2. lenovo123
3. dell123

Please enter your choice:

I need an arraylist menu is because I don't know how many .txt files are in the directory at any given time.

```
import java.io.File;

public class ListFiles 
{

    public static void listRecord() {

  // Directory path here
  String path = "."; 

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
       if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT"))
       {
          System.out.println(files);
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

Here is the class that will display the information in the .txt file onto the console. It stills need some modifying too but I could probably figure that out.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This program reads a text file line by line and print to the console. It uses
 * FileOutputStream to read the file.
 * 
 */
public class DisplayRec {

    public static void displayRecord() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("williamguo5.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);

      // Here BufferedInputStream is added for fast reading.
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

      // dis.available() returns 0 if the file does not have more lines.
      while (dis.available() != 0) {

      // this statement reads the line from the file and print it to
        // the console.
        System.out.println(dis.readLine());
      }

      // dispose all the resources after using them.
      fis.close();
      bis.close();
      dis.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

So the question is: How do I implement a `ArrayList` menu into my `ListFiles` class so it will display the **.txt** files.

Comment: How do I implement a ArrayList menu into my ListFiles class so it will display the .txt files.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such. Now, what have you tried? What didn't work? Do you even have a `menu` class/method yet?

Comment: Did you try making an ArrayList and adding matching files to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alternate method signature for [File.listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) to simplify your code:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

And unless you really enjoy writing loops, you don't even need to manually loop over the array to convert it to a `List`:

```
List<File> lstRecords = Arrays.asList(files);
```

Your `displayRecord` method was pretty close; you just needed to pass the file as an argument and use that instead of a hard-coded filename, and you needed to initialize `dis`.

Putting it all together:

```
package com.example.file;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FileExample {

    public static List<File> listRecords(File dir) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
            }
        });

        return Arrays.asList(files);
    }

    public static void displayRecord(File file) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Here BufferedInputStream is added for fast reading.
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            String line = dis.readLine();
            while (line != null) {

                // this statement reads the line from the file and print it to
                // the console.
                System.out.println(line);
                line = dis.readLine();
            }

            // dispose all the resources after using them.
            fis.close();
            bis.close();
            dis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<File> lstRecords = listRecords(new File("."));
        for (File record : lstRecords) {
            displayRecord(record);
        }
    }

}
```

It's also better to use Reader/Writer instead of InputStream/OutputStream if you're working with text files, and you should close your files in the `finally` block to avoid a potential resource leak.

You'll also notice I didn't explicitly use an `ArrayList`.  In most cases, it's better to program against the interface (in this case, `List`) as much as possible, and only declare variables using the implementing class when you need to use a method that's only available to that class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your sticking point above is the array. If you just need to iterate over the files in a directory, something as simple as the following will do the trick.

```
import java.io.File;


public class TxtEnumerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TxtEnumerator te = new TxtEnumerator();
        te.listFiles();
    }

    public void listFiles() {
        String filepath = "." + File.separator + "textDirectory";
        File file = new File(filepath);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```